# Xamarin: SSO using B2C from Android to Webview

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, webview, azure-active-directory

I have a B2C tenant that I use to authenticate users for a website as well as my Xamarin App, and it works great.
However I found my self in a situation where I need to access my website (through a WebView) from my Android App, and I don't want to make my users sign in to the same B2C tenant again. Is there some way I can send the token with the WebView to my Website and have the user be authenticated automatically?

Comment: Not sure. Perhaps you could create a new page on your website that you can POST your token to, and then authenticate and redirect to the real page you want to load?